# Combine Mulitdimensional Arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a mysql query that counts number of calls over time intervals (using Select Case and Count).  I perform a query for each type of call, in this case a NP_call and Other Call. I am trying to combine my resulting arrays to have one array with the call counts for each time interval.  I am having difficulty combining the arrays. Here is the query I would use for NP_calls

```
SELECT CASE WHEN calldate between 08:00:00 and 08:29:59 then 08:00 (etc ...)
END AS interval
Count(channel) as NP_calls
FROM calls
WHERE cid like '%np%'
GROUP BY calldate
```

my arrays are as follows $arr3 would be the resulting combined array:

```
    $arr1 = Array ( [0] => Array ( [interval] => 07:00 [NP_calls] => 1) 
                    [1] => Array ( [interval] => 08:00 [NP_calls] => 2) 
                    [2] => Array ( [interval] => 08:30 [NP_calls] => 3) 
                    [3] => Array ( [interval] => 10:00 [NP_calls] => 11) 
                    [4] => Array ( [interval] => 11:00 [NP_calls] => 2)) 

    $arr2 = Array ( [0] => Array ( [interval] => 07:00 [Other_calls] => 8)   
                    [1] => Array ( [interval] => 07:30 [Other_calls] => 10)                 
                    [2] => Array ( [interval] => 09:00 [Other_calls] => 11)   
                    [3] => Array ( [interval] => 10:00 [Other_calls] => 14) 
                    [4] => Array ( [interval] => 10:30 [Other_calls] => 16))

    $arr3 = Array ( [0] => Array ( [interval] => 07:00 [NP_calls] => 1     
                          [Other_calls] => 8 ) 
                    [1] => Array ( [interval] => 07:30 [Other_calls] => 10 ) 
                    [2] => Array ( [interval] => 08:00 [NP_calls] => 2) 
                    [3] => Array ( [interval] => 08:30 [NP_calls] => 3 ) 
                    [4] => Array ( [interval] => 09:00 [Other_calls] => 11 ) 
                    [5] => Array ( [interval] => 10:00 [NP_calls] => 11  
                                   [Other_calls] => 14 ) 
                    [6] => Array ( [interval] => 10:30 [Other_calls] => 16 ) 
                    [7] => Array ( [interval] => 11:00 [NP_calls] => 2)
```

In a table this is what i am trying to get as a result ** notice there is nothing at 09:30 as there were no calls then.

```
    interval    NP_calls    Other_calls
    07:00       1           8   
    07:30                   10
    08:00       2           
    08:30       3           
    09:00                   11
    10:00       11          14
    10:30                   16              
    11:00       2
```

If someone can figure out how to do it in the query even better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over both of your arrays and created the combined array using the interval as the key, like this:

```
foreach ($arr1 as $np) {
    $combined[$np['interval']]['NP_calls'] = $np['NP_calls'];
}
foreach ($arr2 as $other) {
    $combined[$other['interval']]['Other_calls'] = $other['Other_calls'];
}
```

This will generate a combined array like this:

```
$combined = array(
    '07:00' => array('NP_calls' => 1, 'Other_calls' => 8),
    '07:30' => array('Other_calls' => 10),
    '08:00' => array('NP_calls' => 2),
    '08:30' => array('NP_calls' => 3), 
    '09:00' => array('Other_calls' => 11), 
    '10:00' => array('NP_calls' => 11, 'Other_calls' => 14),
    '10:30' => array('Other_calls' => 16), 
    '11:00' => array('NP_calls' => 2)
);
```

Comment: I am getting close this is what I get as a result:
Array ( [] => Array ( [NPcalls] => [OTHERcalls] => ) )

Comment: @Bryan the array keys in your comment here are not the same ones shown in your question. Be sure that the keys you use in the loops exactly match the keys in the arrays you are looping over, including case.

Comment: Thanks Panic, I had to get rid of the underscore in mysql query for some reason, but these names npcalls , intrvl and othercalls are reflective.  after correcting a typo, I get the following, which appears to be the last row of the table: Array ( [] => Array ( [npcalls] => 1 [othercalls] => 2 ) )  The data is real data so the values have changed slightly.

Comment: Panic, it worked as you could probably have guessed I had a typo.  Thanks!

Comment: Panic, How do I sort the resulting array by index?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

At MySQL Side you can use inner join or left join for combined the table data

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

OR

At PHP side you can use array_merge function for combine two different arrays

Comment: I am only querying 1 table and when I use merge I do not get the third column but overwritten  keys and values.